# Memory unstable in render script when calling forEach() function

Tags: android, cpu-usage, convolution, renderscript

My algorithm convolution return true result only when Logcat report 1 or 2 CPUS used. In case 3 or more CPUS, the results are quite bad.

So how to limit the number of CPUs run the renderscript threads ?

[image: The result in 2 different running with the same code]

Note: the first result is true and is the same in 2pic, what happen to the others is very considered

Not2: the results on logcat are from Android framework and wouldn't be affected by parallel computing when call rsDebug().

### UPDATE:

I think this is expression of memory unstable when calling forEach() function, my rs code was:

```
    float* x;
    float* h;
int position; // init position = -1;
void conv(float* y){
  posiotion ++;
  // y = x[position+-delta] covolution h[position+- delta]
  // with delta is my algorithm and assured return true result with short input x and h
  // but wrong with x.length == 7000 or more
}
```

I replace with this code and accuracy of result improved when x.length is big:

```
    float* x;
    float* h;
int position; // init position = 0;
void conv(float* y){
  // y[position] = x[position+-delta] covolution h[position+- delta]
  postion++;
}
```

My question is: what cause the unstable? Any experience or document is appreciated. I google hours but have not found anything yet.

Comment: Have you checked, or asked a more senior developer to review your Renderscript code, that it is thread-safe and free of [race-condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) ? That is, it is not trying to write values to the same place from one thread and then reading from the same place from another thread.

Comment: If a program's final output (the images, not the logging) changes according to the number of CPUs it is run on, it is a sign of [indeterminacy](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~keller/courses/cs156/s98/slides/025.html), which strongly indicates the program is not thread-safe.

Comment: Thank rwong, I get what you said. I had thought about it and I fixed this problem with another method.
RScode before:
float* h;
float* x;
conv(float *y){
 // y[position] = convolution of x and h
}
this returned true with short input x and h, but wrong with big ones
Rscode after:
conv() // without float*y parameters

I'm not sure what happen to the memory, but I replace unstable memory code with stable one. I think this replacement make program slower but accuracy is improved

Comment: I'm writing convolution for sound processing, not for image. So with 1 output cell convolution I have to access another memory cell. I think this make memory unstable when calling foreach_conv(y). Do you have any other idea to make memory more stable? I think foreach() is faster than invoke().But I have to use invoke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're printing to the logcat from inside the RenderScript kernel, right?

If so, are you checking the *actual* image that gets generated, or only the logcat output? In general, what gets printed in the logcat is not necessarily in order, because each thread may not be executed in order. This is especially true because RenderScript is a very multithreaded / parallel framework.

Try this. Instead of printing only the result, print also in the same logcat line the X and Y coordinates of the image pixel that result corresponds to. You'll then be able to properly compare if the results for the same pixel are really the same across different runs.

And just to answer what you actually asked about: It's not possible to specify which (or how many) devices a RenderScript kernel runs on. That's just part of how RS was designed to work, it chooses itself the most optimal way to execute at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Actually, this is from Android framework, the result had returned from renderscript and I wrote them to logcat.It is not from rs.

Comment: I have read somewhere that if I didn't chose how many core to compute, the rs would chose the maximum of core by itself. That mean there's someway to limit the core, but I haven't find it up to now.

Comment: limiting the number of cores is something you can do on a development device but not as part of your application: adb shell setprop debug.rs.max-threads <thread count>

Comment: I need to limit the core every time the program run, not only when debug or stick to computer.Anyways, thanks Tim Murray